Desplegar aplicación .net en desarrollo
Estoy montando una aplicación .NET CORE 8 compuesta por varias aplicaciones y librerías de clases que están dispuestas de la siguiente manera:

Varias aplicaciones APIs similares que funcionan como API REST independientes.
Una librería de clases para acceder a la Base de Datos con las
entidades, los repositorios y algunas clases de dominio que usan esos
repositorios para hacer búsquedas.
Una aplicación API (llamémosla Z) que sirve como punto central de la aplicación.
Una aplicación Blazor Server que es el frontend.

La librería de clases está incluida como dependencia en todas las aplicaciones excepto en el front.
La aplicación "Z" incluye como dependencia al resto de aplicaciones APIs para utilizar sus clases y no tener que hacer las llamadas a través de REST, ya que utiliza algunos de sus servicios.
El front incluye como dependencias todas las APIS, tanto la aplicación "Z" como el resto de APIs.
Cada uno de estas aplicaciones tiene su propio repositorio remoto. La idea es que un desarrollador puede descargarse una de las APIs de forma independiente y trabajar con ella. Para ello necesitará la librería de clases de acceso a la BBDD también.
La persona que se descargue la aplicación Z necesitará utilizar todas las APIs y la librería de clases ya que está como dependencia.
Necesitamos una forma rápida y fácil de hacer los despliegues en desarrollo.
Yo que vengo de PHP solía hacer esto con uno o varios Makefile, claro que en php no hay paquetes como en .NET.
Hemos estudiado varias soluciones.

Convertir cada aplicación y librería de clases en un paquete Nuget privado. Esto lo hemos descartado ya que lo vemos más viable para librerías de apoyo, y en estas librerías necesitaremos trabajar muchas veces a la vez en ellas como una solución.
Utilizar submódulos de GIT. También lo hemos probado pero tenemos problemas al desplegar la aplicación "Z" ya que cada API que tiene como dependencia incluye a su vez la librería de clases, y al actuar "Z" como punto de ensamblado se encuentra las clases de esa librería repetidas con el mismo namespace y da conflicto. Esa librería de clases debería ser compartida entre todas las aplicaciones al desplegar "Z".
Probé a utilizar el propio Makefile pero trabajamos en Windows y hay que descargar herramientas de terceros como Chocolatey para ejecutarlo, aunque podría ser una solucion.

¿Que solución adoptaríais vosotros para este caso? (no tiene por que ser una de las de arriba).
También me surge la duda de si cuando Dockerice las aplicaciones, al tener cada una su contenedor tendré problemas al desplegar "Z" y tener tanto Z como las demás aplicaciones sus contenedores, o al quedarse la librería de clases fuera de los contenedores.
Aclarar que el tema de que sean APIs es porque pueden acceder a ellas aplicaciones de terceros a través de API REST, pero tanto en "Z" como en el Frontend nos quitamos ese delay de las llamadas HTTP llamando directamente a las clases de las APIs, hemos aumentado bastante el rendimiento con ésto.

Esto se puede transformar en una discusion eterna entre varias partes, porque obviamente no hay ninguna forma optima de hacer esto.. lo primero que te preguntaria es despliegue en donde??? porque hasta este punto, tenes un monton de librerias que dependen entre si, pero no se donde queres desplegar...

En local por ejemplo. Para que un desarrollador nuevo que entrase pudiese desplegar el proyecto sin dificultad. En php lo hago con Docker, un Makefile, y composer para las librerías de terceros (que sería Nuget en .net). Claro que php no tiene paquetes. Un desarrollador nuevo debería poder hacer un git clone de una de las apis o del proyecto global y poder ejecutarla en su máquina facilmente.

Aca cuando tenemos cosas asi, hacemos una wiki que explica los canales de dependencia y se baja lo necesario y listo. No hay ni tanta rotacion de personas, ni tanta necesidad de andar haciendo algo expecial por mas que sean muchos paquetes. Una vez que bajaste todo, ya se acabo...
